# Angular 2 - Add class based on array string?

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, angular2-template

I'm trying to this list generated by using an array in the component:

```
  billChecklist = [
    {
      title: "mortgage",
      every: "1st",
      amount: "$1300",
      status: "paid"
    }];
```

My HTML has a For LET loop which works fine:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let bills of billChecklist">
    <tr>
       <td>{{bills.every}}</td>
       <td>{{bills.title}}</td>
       <td>{{bills.amount}}</td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-ok': bills.status==='paid'}" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the last , I have a span where I want to put "glyphicon-ok" depending in what is in the array above.

I tried doing a conditional ngClass, but I get an error when using the array variable {{bills.paid}} or nothing at all when using the one below.

```
[ngClass]="{'glyphicon-ok': bills.status==='paid'}"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/63N4n1BEziXtNMMKCHx2.

Comment: Weird, I wonder why it doesn't work for mine???

Comment: We could tell if you posted a complete minimal example, as I just did.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. I had some booleans with the same variable "paid." When I commented it out, it works (picard-facepalm). Thanks for taking the time to test it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the class as following:

```
...[class.glyphicon-ok] = "bills.status==='paid'" ...
```

See more [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#how-to-use)
and

> ```
> > <div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful">   Binds the presence of the
> > CSS class extra-sparkle on the element to the truthiness of the
> > expression isDelightful.
> ```

from [here](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Comment: ooooh! I didn't know you can put the condition on the class in the brackets! You gave me an ah-ha moment!

Comment: When you have only one class to check for, it's more concise :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a full ternary conditional

`<span [ngClass]="{bills.status==='paid' ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-other'}"></span>`